# How to copy from one directory to another when there is a space in the name?

Tags: bash, escaping

I'm trying to figure out how to work with arguments to my bash script when there are spaces in said arguments.

To distill this problem into the simplest possible, consider a script that simply does an `ls` with the provided argument...

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
ls $1
```

Consider the following folder structure:

[image]

When I run it with a folder that has no spaces, it works:

```
$ ./my_ls.sh ~/Documents/Temp/Foo
/Users/user_name/Documents/Temp/Foo
Test
```

When I attempt to do the same with the folder with a space, I get some errors:

```
$ ./my_ls.sh "~/Documents/Temp/Bar Baz"
~/Documents/Temp/Bar Baz
ls: Baz: No such file or directory
ls: ~/Documents/Temp/Bar: No such file or directory
```

I tried using a backslash instead to no avail:

```
$ ./my_ls.sh ~/Documents/Temp/Bar\ Baz
/Users/user_name/Documents/Temp/Bar Baz
ls: /Users/user_name/Documents/Temp/Bar: No such file or directory
ls: Baz: No such file or directory
```

How do I refer to folders/files when there are spaces in their names?

---

I found out that one way to fix the script is to use quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
ls "$1"
```

... and when running the script, use backslash escaping (instead of quotes).

However, this seems counterintuitive, since if we know that backslashes are the way to run the script (`./my_ls.sh ~/Documents/Temp/Bar\ Baz`), why would I use quotes when I run `ls` (`ls "$1"`)? It seems like these should be consistent here. What am I missing? Are there general best practices when dealing with arguments provided by the user (e.g. always assume they are using backslash quotes, and that arguments that refer to directories might have spaces in them)?

---

What's even more odd is that when I use quotes with `ls` via the command line, it fails:

```
$ ls "~/Documents/Temp/Bar Baz"
ls: ~/Documents/Temp/Bar Baz: No such file or directory
```

Why, then, is adding quotes in the bash script the way to go?

Comment: You can also run `./my_ls.sh "$HOME/Documents/Temp/Bar Baz"`.  There are many ways to quote.  Choose what you like.

Comment: The reason `ls "~/Documents..."` fails is that the `~` doesn't get expanded to $HOME

Comment: Don't worry about how the user passed the argument.  Whether the user enters `./my_ls.sh foo\ bar` or `./my_ls.sh "foo bar"`, the first argument will in each case be the string `foo bar`

Comment: You don't have to quote everything, either. `./my_ls.sh ~/Documents/Temp/"Bar Baz"` will work as well.